# Device Admin Receiver get attempted password?

Tags: android

Is it possible to retrieve the used password when onPasswordFailed is called on the device admin receiver? It only looks like you can get the number of attempts but thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to retrieve the used password when onPasswordFailed is called on the device admin receiver?

No. For starters, it may not be a password, but rather something else (fingerprint, pattern).